# .NET MAUI (iOS) : MidiPort.Send is obsolete since iOS 14 - no other way for sending MIDI via CoreMIDI on iOS available?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui, coremidi

I am using .NET MAUI, but focusing only on iOS right now, I cannot find a way (an API) to send MIDI on iOS.

Naturally it would be CoreMidi and the `MidiPort` class using its `Send` method, but as the source states, since iOS 14 its not supported any more

```cs
[ObsoletedOSPlatform("macos11.0")]
[ObsoletedOSPlatform("ios14.0")]
[SupportedOSPlatform("ios")]
[SupportedOSPlatform("maccatalyst")]
[SupportedOSPlatform("macos")]
[UnsupportedOSPlatform("macos11.0")]
[UnsupportedOSPlatform("ios14.0")]
public MidiError Send(MidiEndpoint endpoint, MidiPacket[] packets);
```

I can retrieve a valid `MidiDevice`, `MidiEntity` and `MidiEndpoint`(which are related to the CoreMidi "Network" session / port), but after that I am stuck - theoretically I got all to call `MidiPort.Send`(see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coremidi.midiport.send), but the method is not available in iOS 16.

And by the way, that is not the only obsolete CoreMIDI API - the Xamarin iOS MIDI sample has same issues : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/miditest/.

Any Ideas?

cheers
Ayaphi

Comment: have your read the Apple docs to see what the suggested replacement is?

Comment: Hi Json, the problem is that CoreMIDI native binding is not 1:1. Back in the days Xamarin has build an object oriented API around the "C alike" API of CoreMIDI - see : https://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2012/Sep-11.html - which is still alive in .NET MAUI. Even if there is a replacement, its not visible and available in .NET MAUI.

Comment: Hello, did you found a way to send midi ? I'm facing the same issue here.